# Create a cakephp filter for fail2ban

Tags: regex, logging, cakephp, filter, fail2ban

i would like to create a filter in fail2ban for searching and blocking bad request like "Controller class * could not be found."
For this problem i was create a cakephp.conf file in the filter.d directory in fail2ban. The Content:

```
[Definition]

failregex = ^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}.*Error:.*\nStack Trace:\n(\-.*|\n)*\n.*\n.*\nClient IP: <HOST>\n$

ignoreregex =
```

My example error log looks like this:

```
...
2020-10-08 19:59:46 Error: [Cake\Http\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller class Webfig could not be found. in /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ControllerFactory.php on line 158
Stack Trace:
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ControllerFactory.php:46
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php:249
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:77
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/authentication/src/Middleware/AuthenticationMiddleware.php:122
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:77
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Middleware/CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php:146
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:58
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php:172
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php:68
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php:121
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:58
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php:90
- /home/myapplication/htdocs/webroot/index.php:40

Request URL: /webfig/
Referer URL: http://X.X.X.X/webfig/
Client IP: X.X.X.X
...
```

- X.X.X.X are replaced

But i can't match any ip adresses. The fail2ban tester says:

```
root@test:~# fail2ban-regex /home/myapplication/htdocs/logs/error.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/cakephp.conf

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : cakephp, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : /home/myapplication/htdocs/logs/error.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [719] {^LN-BEG}ExYear(?P<_sep>[-/.])Month(?P=_sep)Day(?:T|  ?)24hour:Minute:Second(?:[.,]Microseconds)?(?:\s*Zone offset)?
`-

Lines: 15447 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 15447 missed
[processed in 10.02 sec]

Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 15447 lines
```

i can't see any problems. Can you help me? :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your log is poor suitable to parse - it is a multiline log-file (IP takes place in other line as the failure message).
Let alone the line with IP does not has any ID (common information with line of failure), it can be still worse if several messages are crossing (so Client IP from other message that is not a failure, coming after failure message).

If you can change the log-format better do that (so date, IP and failure sign are in the same line), e.g. if you use nginx, organize a conditional logging for access log from php-location in error case like this.
See [Fail2ban :: wiki :: Best practice](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/Best-practice) for more info.

If you cannot do that (well better would be to change it), you can use multi-line buffering and parsing using `maxlines` parameter and `<SKIPLINES>` regex.

Your filter would be something like that:

```
[Definition]

# we ignore stack trace, so don't need to hold buffer window too large,
# 5 would be enough, but to be sure (if some log-messages crossing):
maxlines = 10
ignoreregex = ^(?:Stack |- /)
failregex = ^\s+Error: \[[^\]]+\] Controller class \S+ could not be found\..*<SKIPLINES>^((?:Request|Referer) URL:.*<SKIPLINES>)*^Client IP: <HOST>
```

To test it directly use:

```sh
fail2ban-regex --maxlines=5 /path/to/log '^\s+Error: \[[^\]]+\] Controller class \S+ could not be found\..*<SKIPLINES>^((?:Request|Referer) URL:.*<SKIPLINES>)*^Client IP: <HOST>' '^(?:Stack |- /)'
```

But as already said, it is really ugly - better you find the way to log everything in a single line.